# Some intelligent way to dump large structs to text file

Tags: c, file, struct, structure, asn.1

I am writing a piece of code for converting ASN.1 BER binary to CSV text. I have (rather large) structures for all of my ASN types which are to be written in an output text file.
Now I can use normal ways to write the elements one by one (as the output file must be plain text) but I am looking for some clever way to handle this. I hope I could get some tips/tricks and suggestions to do this.

A sample structure (actual structures are *much* larger):

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned    short   intrecordType;
    unsigned    long    long    int  callingNumber;
    unsigned    long    long    int  calledNumber;
    char recordingEntity[7];
    char mscIncomingTKGP[4];
    char mscOutgoingTKGP[4];
    char seizureTime[9];
    char answerTime[9];
    char releaseTime[9]
    struct 
    {
        int gsm0408Cause;
        int gsm0902MapErrorValue;
        int ccittQ767Cause;
        int networkSpecificCause;
        int manufacturerSpecificCause;
    } diagnostics;
    unsigned    long    long    int  callReference;
    int  sequenceNumber;
    int  lastLongPartInd;
    int  recordExtensions;
    char  exchangeIdentity[MAX_IA5STRING_SIZE];
} IncGatewayRec;
```

there are 33 such structures (about 60-70 elements in each) and their corresponding structures for storing flags, to note which fields were populated and which weren't (same structures, only the all of the data types as `unsigned short int` to store flags)

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the text file? To be re-read later by another program, to be human-readable, or what?

Comment: Reread by another program. Actually its meant to be loaded into a Teradata Database using Fastload or Parallel Transporter utility, neither of which supports ASN.1 BER.

Answer (score 1):

Write a program that parses a struct declaration, and generates a print function.

Comment: hmm, that'll be very generic, but very useful indeed. thanks for the idea.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some commercial ASN.1 tools (such as the one from [OSS Nokalva](http://www.oss.com)) have the ability for you to replace the fprintf() function with your own if its regular function to print the decoded message is not sufficient for you.  Consider downloading a free trial of the OSS ASN.1 Tool to see if that will work for you.

Comment: i have all of the ASN.1 functionality implemented. In fact, my question is about ideas on some nice way to implement the fprintf() replacement for my functions.

Comment: If you are using a commercial tool (such as the one from OSS) their technical support will help you with this.  If you are using a free ASN.1 tool, you may need to write your own code for handling this.